# On a slight incline, How do I construct a wooden garage floor that is level, floating and not-anchored?

Tags: shed

Here is the situation_
I am about to start building a shed/garage in my back yard, the whole yard slopes away at about 2-3 degrees from the house.

The yard is currently block-paved (bricks) in the standard fashion.

I dont want to take these bricks up as i might be moving in a year or so. I want to build this shed on-top of this surface.

What would be the best method for building a wooden (floating/not anchored) shed base on this? I also want to park a (small) car in this so must be quite low to the ground on the side closest to the house, and be able to take the weight.

The base will need to be about 12 ft square.
I'm basically creating a huge wedge-shaped base...

Comment: Very different approaches depending on whether you are building a small 8x10 wood floor shed or a 20x25 cement floor garage.

Comment: Sorry wasnt very clear (edited to be)
Im looking to make a 12x12ft WOODEN base/floor

Comment: honestly, if you didnt need to park your car in it, I would set it up on 4 pallets or more depending on the size, shimmy the PALLETS up to nix the wedge, use a ramp for lawnmower etc...but with a car...hmm...

Comment: Might a pole barn style be a better choice here? i.e. don't build a floor, just walls and a roof. I don't think floating/not anchored is the way to go--you don't want this thing sliding down the incline as you brake the vehicle to a stop inside. No floor would solve these problems.

Comment: I think it would be BEST to be flat, if for example the car's handbrake failed, it would roll through the back of the shed!
Just as reference its an old mini, so doesnt weigh a LOT, but enough to have design considerations.